# Excel VBA to Word, Find and Replace second instance

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a bunch of word documents with three $ in them.

I need to change the second $.

Currently using this format of .find I can only change the first and last $ by toggling forward as true/false.

Which is kind of weird because looking at it you think it would loop through the entire page and replace every one (which is not what I want anyways).

I tried a different format with `wdReplaceAll` using .execute replace and then running the two other finds to just re-replace the first and last finds, but ran into a problem with .Expand Unit not working.

Is there a simple like +1 counter I could be using to do this?  It seems like the find immediately ends after being executed and I can't figure out a way to get to my second $.

```vb
For Each oRange In WordDoc.StoryRanges
    With oRange
        With .Find
            .Forward = True
            .Text = "$"
        End With
        If .Find.Execute Then
            .Expand Unit:=4
            .Text = Price
        End If
    End With
Next oRange
```

Comment: _It seems like the find immediately ends after being executed_ well, yes: `.Find.Execute` unsurprisingly executes the `Find` method, once.  If you want to execute a second time, code it a second time.

Comment: When I code it a second time it runs the same find and doesn't jump to the next search result.

Comment: I ran a small test before commenting.  `If .Find.Execute Then If .Find.Execute Then  .Expand Unit:=4 .Text = Price  End If  End If` found the second instance for me.

Comment: That works, thanks.

Comment: This is a really good explanation of how Words VBA find works: [Word's Fickle VBA .Find Property](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/words_fickle_vba_find_property.html). I bookmarked it as I now and then get lost again with find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter in the following way

```
For Each oRange In WordDoc.StoryRanges
    Instance = 0 ' If you want to reset for each story range
    With oRange
        Do While .Find.Execute("$")
            Instance = Instance + 1
            If Instance = 2 Then
                .Expand Unit:=4
                .Text = Price
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End With
Next oRange
```